# Adding a bookmark to a new folder in Safari?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, bookmarks

In Chrome, when adding a new bookmark, you can choose to add it to a new folder you create at that time, through "Choose Another Folder" > "New Folder".

However, in Safari, I find if I need to do this, I have to go create the folder first in my bookmarks, then add the bookmark to this folder.

Is there any way I could do the same thing as Chrome in Safari?

Comment: no answers so far, so… I don't know of a way. Always folder first, afaik

Answer (score 1):

That is the only way in Safari.

Create the New folder first then add bookmarks to it.